# iscroll: image carousel like App Store

Tags: carousel, iscroll

We are working on a mobile web application. The designer likes the image carousel effect on App Store (the screenshots of the an App). So we try to mimic the same effect using JavaScript.

We are using [iScroll](http://iscrolljs.com/) to implement. So here is a customization of its [demo carousel](http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll5/demos/carousel/): http://jsfiddle.net/0t9savgj/. The options are:

```
{
    scrollX: true,
    scrollY: false,
    momentum: false,
    snap: true,
    snapSpeed: 400,
    keyBindings: true,
    indicators: {
        el: document.getElementById('indicator'),
        resize: false
    }
});
```

The problem is: for the last image, there is always some extra space, which is unwanted:

[image]

Does any one knows how to solve this? Or some other JS libraries implementing the same carousel? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploration, the only way is to use the `scroll` event of `iscroll-probe.js`. Manually stop the scrolling when reaching the right border. But the indicators are not exact.